# Error when embed python script in C in VS2017

Tags: python, c, embed

I write a simple C code to embed python script,but when I run it in VS2017,it looks well untill return.It shows that error happens in exe_common.inl.However, I can't find where is wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Python.h>

int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();

    PyRun_SimpleString("print('Hello world!')");

    Py_Finalize();

    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run this using codeblocks 17.12 it gave me an error saying 
"fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory"

I think there is no such inbuilt header file as " < Python.h >"

Comment: You should configure python path in your ide just like configure Third party libraries.